# Insert value of a select with axios in reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

I'm developing an app in React.Js and for some reason it is not saving the value that is selected in the select.

```
    const App = () => {
        // is obtained from another api: REQUEST_API_GET
        const Dates = dates.map(item => ({
            value: item.Name,
            label: item.Name,
        }));
    
        const [date, setDate] = React.useState({
            Name: ''
        });
    
        function handleChangeDate(event) {
            setDate({
                Name: event.value
              })
        }
    
        const addDate = (date) => {
            axios.post(`${REQUEST_API_POST}`, {date});
        };
    
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <NoSsr>
                        <Select
                            classes={classes}
                            styles={selectStyles}
                            inputId="date"
                            TextFieldProps={{
                                label: 'Date',
                                InputLabelProps: {
                                htmlFor: 'date',
                                shrink: true,
                                },
                                placeholder: 'Search',
                            }}
                            options={date}
                            components={components}
                            value={date.Name}
                            onChange={handleChangeDate}
                        />
                    </NoSsr>
    
                    <a onClick={() => addDate()}>add</a>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }

export default App;
```

It seems to take the value when I select it, you can see in `handleChangeDate` if put a `console.log`, but in `addDate` it is not taking it.

How can I fix it, suggestions?

Comment: also check if you date is empty before posting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling **addDate()** function you are not passing any argument, but in your parameter you have specified date as a parameter (that too without any default value). I think you are trying to access the value of **date**, which is a **state**, and state can be accessed anywhere in the function, so no need to pass it as a parameter.

```
enter code here
const addDate = () => {
    axios.post(`${REQUEST_API_POST}`, {date});
};
```

**Use this and it will work fine**

You can also pass date (state) as an argument in you function **addData**, something
like this(addData(date)) and this will work too. **but first approach is better**

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have put a `console.log` in `addDate` and return: name: "". Can you post an example?

Comment: the code i have written above in the answer will work fine. When you use state than it can be accessed anywhere in function so there is no need to pass it as an argument, just use the state value directly

Comment: is returning an object, shouldn't it insert an element?

Comment: what you want to pass as data to your axios request?

if you want to pass the data object you can user {date} or {date: date} (they both are same only, use any of them);
if you want to pass the value of key (Name) in api request as data than you can pass {date: date.Name}, i hope you get the point now

Comment: if I add `name: '20202` in `addDate` it inserts it. I will try what you tell me

Comment: what do you want to pass as data in you post request?

Comment: The code is simplified, I want to pass three values that come from three different select

Answer (score 2):

Just at looking at your code it is obvious that you are not actually using the proper data in your `addDate` handler.

You need to pass the `state` value in the param or even better directly in your callback as follows:

```
const addDate = () => {
    axios.post(`${REQUEST_API_POST}`, {date}); // here your date is your state!
};
```

Since you are not passing any parameters, you can improve your callback in your `onClick` like that too :

```
<a onClick={addDate}>add</a>
```

Another detail, it's more common to have your object properties as lowercase values hence `Name` to `name`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I applied the changes suggested but not yet save the selected value, have put a `console.log` in `addDate` and return: `name: ""`

Comment: if it is numeric the value inserts it if it is a string it does not insert it, why?

Answer (score 2):

The variable date you're using in addDate is not the hook.
Just remove date parameter.

```
    const addDate = () => { // <-- no date in input
        axios.post(`${REQUEST_API_POST}`, {date});
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have put a `console.log` in `addDate` and return: name: "". Can you post an example?

Comment: Look at the code in the answer. If you remove the input parameter in your addDate function it should work.

Comment: is returning an object, shouldn't it insert an element? if I add `name: '20202` in `addDate` it inserts it

Comment: if it is numeric the value inserts it if it is a string it does not insert it, why?